# Which address to mention in Previous Employer details for DS-160

Tags: visas, h1b-visas

I was working for company which is in Chennai and I am working from Pune from my Home.
I am applying for a US H1B visa, and I am confused about how to fill in the previous employer details such as address.

Which address shall I mention in Previous employer address? whether Chennai office address or my home address?

Can anybody help?

Comment: On the [guide I looked at](https://www.immihelp.com/visas/ds-160-form/previous-work-education-training-information.html) it advises: **Employer's complete address**. That won't be your home address. Same with their phone number: not your home phone but the company's phone.

Comment: @DJClayworth It's about visa applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of them asking for your employer's address is that they want to be able to contact them. Giving them your home address will not help them. Give the address of the office that you interacted with, or if there isn't such a place the company HQ in your country.

Comment: Will it be okay to say that I was working from Home for my previous company if asked by interviewer?

Comment: Yes absolutely.

Comment: Also my current employer is in Chennai and I am doing Work From Home for him as well, so do I also need to mention Chennai office address for my Current Employement ?

Comment: Yes. Always give an address where people can contact your employer. That's what they want to know.

Answer (score 1):

It asks for the address of your employer – the company – not your address.